# Is it possible to accelerate my office's stream capture process?

Tags: audio, video, performance, streaming, video-capture

Hoping someone has had experience with this roadblock.

As a law office, one of our tasks is to capture court proceedings that were streamed within the last couple of days. This task is complicated by the fact that the proceedings are often several hours long and we only have one license to the site, so we cannot capture multiple proceedings at a time.

My first solution, which failed, was to speed up the stream to x2 and then slow the capture to .5, hopefully to cut the capture time in half. Unfortunately,this also rendered the audio (and by consequence, the capture itself) worthless as it was not possible to understand what was being said. Does anyone have any ideas that I could try, as I've been racking my brain for solutions and have only come up with the one.

The site I'm capturing streams from is Courtroom View Network (https://cvn.com) and the capture software currently used is Camtasia 2018.

Comment: Any enhancements to the stream capture speed is going to depend heavily on the features of the server and content players employed by the CVN site.

Comment: What format is the video in? Can you just download the file instead of re-recording it?

Comment: @music2myear very true, as it turns out speeding it up simply destroys audio clarity and slowing down the capture in Camtasia pitches the audio down, creating a truly worthless result.

Comment: @szatmary I assume they are streaming it as an mp4, would be surprising if it turned out to be another format; that said, I don't know for sure. If I could simply download the file, I wouldn't be jumping through so many hoops. Unfortunately the site does not provide access to downloadable files, only the stream so the working solution at my job before I took this position was to screen capture. I assume there is some third party software or else that can provide me with that functionality, but not sure.

Comment: There are better streaming formats than MP4, so it wouldn't be surprising if was something different. `Unfortunately the site does not provide access to downloadable files`: But it does! From the server perspective, there is no difference between streaming and downloading. Your browser decides if it is played, or saved to disk. You can look at the network tab of the browser and see all the files its downloading. Then use something like wget. This of course assumes they are not using DRM.

Comment: @szatmary I assumed that since the software has an expensive license, it is likely employing DRM. If you're frustrated with how many assumptions I'm making, so am I. I am not an admin on the network where I work and also do not have privileged account access for many of these sites, so I am stuck experimenting a lot of the time. Could you elaborate a little more on using wget (or however you recommend scraping the data off the server) to collect that data?